# Following R error happened : caught bus error, address 0x7f..., cause non-existent physical address

Tags: ram, r

Test environment :

uname -r

```
5.4.0-107-generic
```

lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

---

I run the R and I get following error

```
*** caught bus error ***
address 0x7f96618407a4, cause 'non-existent physical address'

Traceback:
 1: NextMethod(.Generic)
 2: Ops.numeric_version(R_version_built_under, "3.0.0")
 3: testRversion(pkgInfo, package, pkgpath)
 4: library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,     warn.conflicts = warn.conflicts, quietly = quietly, mask.ok = mask.ok,     exclude = exclude, include.only = include.only, attach.required = attach.required)
 5: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 6: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 7: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 8: tryCatch(library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE,     logical.return = TRUE, warn.conflicts = warn.conflicts, quietly = quietly,     mask.ok = mask.ok, exclude = exclude, include.only = include.only,     attach.required = attach.required), error = function(e) e)
 9: require(pkg, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE, character.only = TRUE)
10: .OptRequireMethods()

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection:
```

If I ctrl+c, normal R script opens up and even command (like calculation 1+1=2 in R script) also works

```
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10) -- "One Push-Up"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

>
```

I searched following error `*** caught bus error *** address 0x7f96618407a4, cause 'non-existent physical address'` and several answers say it's hardware related problem.
But working for other application like code execution with Python and Jupyter notebook works normaly, so I think the hardwares don't seem problmematic.

I uninstalled R by

```
sudo apt-get remove r-base-core
sudo apt-get remove r-base
```

I also removed directories which are searched from `R command> .libPaths()` such as

```
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"      
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

And I reinstalled R but no difference with same above error `*** caught bus error *** address 0x7f96618407a4, cause 'non-existent physical address'`

And I need to run R studio server and I get this error
[image]

and the log output from `rstudio-server status` is like the following

```
● rstudio-server.service - RStudio Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rstudio-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-04-03 14:19:12 KST; 57min ago
  Process: 4604 ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall -TERM rserver (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4835 ExecStart=/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4836 (rserver)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 12287)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rstudio-server.service
           └─4836 /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver

 4, 03 14:19:12 resso225 systemd[1]: Starting RStudio Server...
 4, 03 14:19:12 resso225 systemd[1]: Started RStudio Server.
 4, 03 14:19:13 resso225 rserver[4836]: ERROR R did not return any output when queried for directory location information; LOGGED FROM: bool rstudio::core::r_util::{anonymous}::detectRLocationsUsingR(const string&, rstudio::core::FilePath*, rstudio::core::FilePath*, rstudio::
 4, 03 14:19:13 resso225 rserver[4836]: ERROR system error 71 (Protocol error) [description: Unable to parse version from R, version-info: , r-error: 
                                           *** caught bus error ***
                                          address 0x7f964bc637a4, cause 'non-existent physical address'
                                          
                                          Traceback:
                                           1: NextMethod(.Generic)
                                           2: Ops.numeric_version(R_version_built_under, "3.0.0")
                                           3: testRversion(pkgInfo, package, pkgpath)
                                           4: library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,     warn.conflicts = warn.conflicts, quietly = quietly, mask.ok = mask.ok,     exclude = exclude, include.only = include.only, attach.required = atta
                                           5: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
                                           6: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
                                           7: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
                                           8: tryCatch(library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE,     logical.return = TRUE, warn.conflicts = warn.conflicts, quietly = quietly,     mask.ok = mask.ok, exclude = exclude, include.only = include.only,     attach.re
                                           9: require(pkg, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE, character.only = TRUE)
                                          10: .OptRequireMethods()
                                          An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
                                          Bus error (core dumped)
                                          ]; OCCURRED AT rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::r_util::rVersion(const rstudio::core::FilePath&, const rstudio::core::FilePath&, const string&, const string&, const string&, const rstudio::core::FilePath&, std::__cxx11::string*) src
 4, 03 14:56:24 resso225 rserver[4836]: ERROR system error 111 (Connection refused) [request-uri: /rpc/client_init]; OCCURRED AT void rstudio::core::http::LocalStreamAsyncClient::handleConnect(const rstudio_boost::system::error_code&) src/cpp/server/ServerSessionProxy.cpp:124
```

I want to resolve above `caught bus error...` and want to run R studio server. Please help.

---

Additional information

```
> ldd $(type -p R)
not a dynamic executable
```

```
> (set -x ; R) or ldd $(set -x ; R)
+ R

 *** caught bus error ***
address 0x7f593efea7a4, cause 'non-existent physical address'

Traceback:
 1: NextMethod(.Generic)
 2: Ops.numeric_version(R_version_built_under, "3.0.0")
 3: testRversion(pkgInfo, package, pkgpath)
 4: library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,     warn.conflicts = warn.conflicts, quietly = quietly, mask.ok = mask.ok,     exclude = exclude, include.only = include.only, attach.required = attach.required)
 5: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 6: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 7: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 8: tryCatch(library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE,     logical.return = TRUE, warn.conflicts = warn.conflicts, quietly = quietly,     mask.ok = mask.ok, exclude = exclude, include.only = include.only,     attach.required = attach.required), error = function(e) e)
 9: require(pkg, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE, character.only = TRUE)
10: .OptRequireMethods()

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection:
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the version of Ubuntu you’re running? This will make it easier to test 

Comment: @matigo Yes, I added the environment info

Comment: Hello. Most common cause 0f such an error is memory. Have you run an extensive test of the ram in the computer?

Comment: @David Hi, I tested simple data processing python code (using 20 multi processors in parallel). It worked and no above error in other situations yet. This is server having 500GB memory, how do I test the ram effectively to find the cause of error?

Comment: When you boot the machine is there an option to use memtest? If not you need to find a ram testing app. A good test can only be preformed when the computer is not running the OS. I do not have any that I can recommend.

Comment: Are you missing a shared library needed by `R`? The terminal command `ldd $(type -p R)` will show.

Comment: @waltinator Hi. The output from `ldd $(type -p R)` is `not a dynamic executable`. Is it be relevant information?

Comment: I think the `R` is a shell script wrapper that does some setup and then calls the real `R`. You can watch this, and find the real `R` by `(set -x ; R)`.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].  You may click on any of these [edit] links to [edit] your question.

Comment: @waltinator okay, I added the additional check results, but it seems like no useful infomation from `(set -x ; R)`